# Mock offline mode to integration test service-worker

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, service-worker, offline, chai

I have implemented a service worker that is using localforage with indexedDB for caching. Now I want to write some integration tests but am having trouble mocking offline requests.
Ideally, I would like to send a couple of online requests, then swap to offline mode to do some assertions afterward.
I'm using Chai/Mocha to test my Ember.js code but would not mind using alternative tools.

How can I mock being offline from within a test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on my twitter and was told that [Puppeteer](https://github.com/googlechrome/puppeteer/) offers an API that allows one to [set the offline mode](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.8.0&show=api-pagesetofflinemodeenabled) via `page.setOfflineMode(true)`.